# Exception: Key Down / Up events only make sense for modifier keys

Tags: java, selenium

I am working with Java Selenium, testing using the Firefox driver.

I want to send Ctrl + - to my Firefox browser.

This is my code:

```
    Common.myPrint(thisClass + " *** zoomOut ***");
    Actions actionObject = new Actions(driver);
    try {
        actionObject.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).keyUp(Keys.SUBTRACT).perform();

        // reset this counter - basis for request counter

        global.variables.dataTotalCount = 0;

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        int errorCode = 1525182195;
        System.err.println(thisClass + " error code: " + errorCode + " Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```

i am receiving this error message: Exception: Key Down / Up events only make sense for modifier keys.

That is all very well, but how can I send Ctrl & - (to reduce font size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try chord method

```
String selectkeys= Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SUBTRACT);
```

Comment: it will throw a:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: keyDown argument must be an instanceof Keys: ??

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking you can use:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "t"));
```

Except if you are using **Chrome Driver** there is **a bug** that does not allow to send some commands:

These won't work

```
act.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "t"));
act.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "n"));
```

This work:

```
// open in a new tab
driver.findElement(By.id("linkID")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER));
```

At some moment they could solve the bug and it will work again
The bug track: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=581

Answer (score 0):

`keyUp` and `keyDown` only allow the modifier keys as input parameters. All other keys will raise an `IllegalArgumentException`. Use `sendKeys()` from the `Actions` class to perform the operation for other keys. But if you want to press and hold a key, use the `Robot` class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).